# Get the desired view when dealing with fragments when the view's id has a duplicate name in both xml

Tags: android

I'm dealing now with fixed tabs and fragments. I have 2 tabs. But it happened that the 2 xml files are a copy and paste they differ slightly. I do not want to change the id name of each view there. 
The first xml file name is :first.xml
the second is :second.xml

When initializing the views in my main activity extending the 2 fragments (inner classes), how can I determine the desired views if they have the same id name ?

For example:

`TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);` //However, this exists in both first.xml and second.xml , how can I tell it to take it from second.xml and not from first.xml ?
Thank you!

Comment: hmm.. but sometimes we have like 20 tabs and they all have the same ids im' not gonna change all of them. you know what i mean? All I want to do is when a certain tab is selected take the views only from the desired xml.

Comment: You shouldn't simply use the `findViewById()` method when searching for views in a fragment. Use `fragment.getView().findViewByid()`.

Comment: I am a little bit confused....I think You have to change because same id´s will not work....